# how to listen to audio starting from the feature extractions of the deep learning model?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, librosa, speaker

How can I play audio from model.predict return

```
features_test = model.predict(X_test)

x = features_test\[0\]
x = np.expand_dims(x, 0)
ipd.Audio(x\[0,:,0\], rate=16000, autoplay=False)
```

Comment: What kind of neural network is `model` / what does it output?

Comment: my neural network is a ResNet18
    x, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_path, sr=16000)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, 0)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, -1)
    y_pred = model.predict(x)

I want to do attack on y_pred with FGSM and i want to listen the corrupted audio after the attack
    test_features_fgsm_deepfool = attack_fgsm.generate(features_test_scaled)
I need to listen the adversarial speaker from the features extracts